# PHP: Pulling JSON data out of database and displaying it

Tags: php, json

I'm using a php library from https://sourceforge.net/p/wowarmoryapi/home/Home/. It pulls json data from battle.net and stores it in my database for cache reasons.

code to get json from db (I'm not sure if it's still considered json at this point):

```
$data = $con->query('SELECT Data FROM wa_guilds');
```

I use the following code to see the data:

```
foreach($data as $row) {        
    echo "<span style='color:#ff0099'>";
    var_dump($row);
    echo "</span>"; }
```

which looks like this minus the errors, that's from another code:
[image: pink text is the dump]

I've tried various methods, mostly from this site to show my data in a way that's easy to read but I always get error.

1. This is definitely an object. `if (is_object($data))  { echo "yay!"; }` <--this works
2. Once I use `$decodedjson = json_decode($data);` it's no longer an object and I can't seem to print the results to see what it looks like. var_dump($decodedjson) returns NULL

Finally, when I use the following code:

```
foreach ($data as $da){     
    echo $da['Data']['character']['name'];  }
```

returns **Warning: Illegal string offset 'character'**

and:

```
foreach ($data as $da){     
    echo $da['character']['name'];  }
```

returns **Notice: Undefined index: character**

I don't understand what I'd doing wrong, or right. Do I need to somehow turn $data into a string?

### NEW CODE

```
$sth = $con->query('SELECT Data FROM wa_guilds');
$sth->execute();    
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($data as $row) {
    foreach($row as $r) {
        $myData = json_decode($r, true);
        echo "<span style='color:#ff0099'>";
        var_dump($myData['Data']); 
        echo "</span>"; }  }
```

### NEW ERROR

NULL NULL

Comment: What gives a `var_dump($data);` right after the `$data = $con->query()` line? I'm guessing that you are trying to loop on a query reference, instead of the query results.

Comment: @FrostyZ that's all the pink text in the photo. It's so I can read and make sure that someone was actually in the database. Oh yeah, it's in a loop because someone suggested that, I just never changed it. Oh, when I take it out of the loop I get this back: `object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(26) "SELECT Data FROM wa_guilds" }`

Comment: Can you post part of the result of `var_dump($data)`?

Answer (score 1):

From the warning I'm guessing you're using PDO. If `$con` is your PDO instance representing a connection to a database, try the following:

```
$sth = $con->prepare('SELECT Data FROM wa_guilds');
$sth->execute();

$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($data as $row) {
    $myData = json_decode($row['Data'], true);
    echo "<span style='color:#ff0099'>";
    // $myData should now be a PHP array which you can access easily
    print_r($myData);
    echo "</span>";
}
```

Comment: Cool, made those changes. 
`$roster = json_decode($data, true); 
 print $roster;`
returns **Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**
and if i change it to `$roster = json_decode($data['Data'], true);`
it returns **Notice: Undefined index: Data**

But when I just var_dump as you mentioned above it takes away everything before string(100000).

Comment: Can you put on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) the result of one `print_r($row);` instruction in a line between your 2 foreach?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jLMaJLS3 this is from `foreach($data as $row) {
   echo "<span style='color:#ff0099'>";
   var_dump($row['Data']); 
   echo "</span>"; 
  } `

Comment: print_r($row); changes the beginning to look like this:

Array ( [Data] => {"lastModified":1367433943000,"name":"Teh

Comment: Check the updated answer, it should print a PHP array now which you can access easily.

Comment: It returns nothing :(
I'm tempted to ditch this library

Comment: At a glance `$row['Data']` looks like valid JSON. Just for test purposes try to fecth the data directly from the BattleNet API using the library instead of fetching from your DB. Maybe there's something wrong with the way your stored in the DB.

Comment: I've done that part successfully, that's how it was able to be stored in the db. I don't know how it's being stored. I've asked the author but it doesn't look like he responds often. I've decided to not use this library for the time being. Ty for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the json string first, I'm not sure how many rows you are expecting from the DB but if it's only one you don't need the loop:

```
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$decoded = json_decode($data['Data'], true);

echo "<span style='color:#ff0099'>";
var_dump($decoded);
echo "</span>";
```

if you need a loop it should work like this:

```
foreach($data as $d)
{
    $decoded = json_decode($d['Data'], true);

    echo "<span style='color:#ff0099'>";
    var_dump($decoded);
    echo "</span>";
}
```

Comment: that gives me this error: **Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**
**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**
 `$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
 $decoded = json_decode($data, true);
 
 foreach($decoded as $row) {  
  echo "<span style='color:#ff0099'>";
  var_dump($row['Data']);
  echo "</span>"; 
  } `

Comment: My 1st bullet up top says this is coming out as an object and not a string.

Comment: try my edited version :) I think `$data` is in mumeric index `$data[0]...$data[n]`

Comment: Nuts! `Notice: Undefined index: Data` and `NULL` for the first part.
The loop returns `NULL NULL`

Comment: :S `$d['Data']` has to be an array with a `string(100000)` and that string is a JSON object... I'm lost now! lol